# python - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(sys.argv)):
    if sys.argv[i] == "--width":
        if math.isnan(sys.argv[i+1]):
            print("Width specified ({0}) is not a valid integer!".format(sys.argv[i+1]))
            sys.exit()
    else:
        width = int(sys.argv[i+1])
```

Here is my input:

```
python3 main.py --width 1280 --height 720
```

I expect the width and height variable to be set to 1280 and 720, respectively.

Instead, this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    if sys.argv[i] == "--width":
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am somewhat experienced with command-line Python, however this is my first time creating a PyQt app, and using sys.argv in particular. Why do I get this error, and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to index `argv` with a string, your error is very self-explanatory.  `for i in sys.argv` iterates through the elements of `argv`, not the indices.  You probably want `enumerate` here

Comment: `for i in sys.argv` means iterating over each value in `sys.argv` if you really need indices then use `for i in range(len(sys.argv))`. However, it looks like you are trying to parse arguments there is a module for this [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#module-argparse)

Comment: Oh, right. That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `argparse` module instead of rolling your own command-line argument processor.

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("--width", type=int, default=0)
args = p.parse_args()

print("You chose {}".format(args.width))
```

In action:

```
% python tmp.py
You chose 0
% python tmp.py --width 3
You chose 3
% python tmp.py --width foo
usage: tmp.py [-h] [--width WIDTH]
tmp.py: error: argument --width: invalid int value: 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```
for i in range(len(sys.argv)):
    if sys.argv[i] == "--width":
        if math.isnan(sys.argv[i+1]):
            print("Width specified ({0}) is not a valid integer!".format(sys.argv[i+1]))
            sys.exit()
    else:
        width = int(sys.argv[i+1])
```